# can't add SendGrid to existing VB.NET Web app

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio, sendgrid

I have an existing vb.net web app.
I want to add SendGrid functionality.
I did Website men > Manage NuGet, and installed SendGrid.

But when I add 
Imports SendGrid
to a .vb file, it gets squiggly green underline warning that it can't find SendGrid.

The solution explorer > project:  doesn't show a "reference" node, like C# does.

Using VisualStudio 2015.

Comment: What framework you using? It requires 4.5. Thats my best guess as of why it cant find the libraries...